parent to child query inside batchable
Let's say we have
 SELECT Id, Label,
(SELECT SobjectType, PermissionsRead FROM ObjectPerms),
(SELECT SobjectType, Field, PermissionsRead FROM FieldPerms)
FROM PermissionSet
where id in : ids   

will it work inside batchable?
i just wanna avoid 2 queries to get both objectPerms and fieldPerms

yeap, definately
